# Simplify This Conditional Statement

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have this crazy conditional that I just know there is a better way to write. Here is the pseudo code:

```
if( A && B ){
   console.log( 'do not show' );
}

if( A && C ){
   console.log( 'show' );
}

if( A && D ){
   console.log( 'do not show' );
}

if( A && E ) {
   console.log( 'do not show' );
}
```

I'm just really blanking out.

Comment: if(a){console.log((c?'':'do not ')+'show');} ... For maximum minification lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
if (A) {
   if (B || D || E) {
     console.log( 'do not show' );
   } 
   if ( C ) {
     console.log( 'show' );
   }
}
```

If you really wanted to specify separate tasks for each condition, then you could use this, but it's overly complicated if your task is just the above code.

```
var A = C = true;
var B = D = E = false;

function doWhen( cond, fn ) {
    if ( cond === true ) {
        return ( typeof fn === 'function' ? fn() : fn );
    }
    return undefined;
}

doWhen(A, function() {
    [ [B, function() { console.log('b message') }], 
      [C, function() { console.log('c message') }], 
      [D, function() { console.log('d message') }], 
      [E, function() { console.log('e message') }] ]
        .forEach(function(cond) {
            doWhen.apply(null, cond);
        });
});
```

Comment: The original code could produce 3 different 'do not show' messages.

Comment: It could, though the OP does not specify that.

Comment: I'm thinking if the OP wants more control, using a dispatch method, but that seems overkill if they just want to produce the same messages.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this do it:

```
if (A) {
    if(B || D || E){
       console.log( 'do not show' );
    }

    if( C ){
       console.log( 'show' );
    }
}
```

**update**

Or just for fun (if you want every state)

```
switch((a << 0) | (b << 1) | (c << 2) | (d << 3) | (e << 4)) {
    case 3: console.log("A && B"); break;
    case 5: console.log("A && C"); break;
    case 9: console.log("A && D"); break;
    case 17: console.log("A && E"); break;
}
```

A JSFiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/LxvBZ/

Comment: I added an update with bitwise operators. With that, you could catch all of the states.

Answer (score 1):

If you really needed to evaluate `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E` separately, this is pretty straight forward:

```
if( A ){
    if( B ){
       console.log( 'do not show' );
    }

    if( C ){
       console.log( 'show' );
    }

    if( D ){
       console.log( 'do not show' );
    }

    if( E ) {
       console.log( 'do not show' );
    }
}
```

Now if all those `if`'s (after the first) were supposed to be `else if`'s, then this can be simplified to:

```
if( A ){
    if( B || D || E ){
       console.log( 'do not show' );
    }else if( C ){
       console.log( 'show' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I would call this "simplified" though

Comment: @RUJordan It's necessary if OP really wanted to produce three different 'do not show' methods.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
if ( A ) {
    if( B || D || E ){
       console.log( 'do not show' );
    }

    if( C ){
       console.log( 'show' );
    }
}
```

Comment: What about condensing even further? `if (B || D || E) {}`

Answer (score 0):

```
if( A ){
    var printOnLog = '';
    if( B || C || E ){
       printOnLog = 'do not show';
    }

    else if( C ){
       printOnLog = 'show';
    }

    else {
      //default action
    }

   console.log(printOnLog);
}
```

Well, I think that it's impossible to have multiple conditions, if this is true use "else if" to avoid usless if.

If it's possible (A && B) && (A && C), just use normal "if"

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
if (A) {
    if (C) {
        console.log("show");
    }
    else if (B || D || E) {
        console.log("do not show");
    }
 }
```

or this if you prefer:

```
if (A && C) {
    console.log("show");
}
else if (A && (B || D || E)) {
    console.log("do not show");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a ternary operator is kind of the same thing. You could use it to shrink the code.

To add more conditions to the ternary operator, use ' ? ' to specify if conditions and ' : ' for specifying else conditions. It has to end with a final else condition however, like shown below.

```
var output = ((A && B) || (A && D) || (A && E)) ? "do not show" : (A && C) ? "show" : "";
console.log(output);
```

Comment: your code is not equivalent to code inside the question in case when A is false

Comment: What are you talking about? Based on the OP's code, he's only checking if 'A' AND another variable is equal to true.

Comment: From the pseudocode, if A is false, there is no output at all. Please check the other answers to see handling of this condition. As we do not know whether we are permitted returning something if A is false, equivalent solution is not to return "do not show" or "" in that case, i.e. skip any evaluation in that case.

Comment: Okay, I finally realized what you were saying. My code was inequivalent because it returned something whether 'A' was true or false. I automatically assumed that he set 'A' as true, so I neglected to test for when 'A' is false. I get it though. Since he did not provide the values for the variables, you have to test for all possible values. Thanks, a bit inexperienced at programming and practically a baby here.